# Rxjs Subject next or onNext

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm quite new at rxjs stuff be patience.
For example in this tutorial
http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/
but I saw the same code in the ng-book

I can see

```
let subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.subscribe(value => console.log('Received new subject value: '))
subject.next(newValue);
```

but if I put the code in the browser I've got

s**ubject.next is not a function**

so if I take a look to the doc
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.subscribe(value => console.log('Received new subject value: ',value))
subject.onNext(2);
```

Can you explain me why the tutorial and the book
are using next ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems you're using the wrong rxjs version (4.x). Angular2 uses rxjs 5 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/

See also http://reactivex.io/rxjs/