# angular2 Observarble onError not a function

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am trying to create an observable but my code fails:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this._log.debug('SecureHttpService#get: ' + url);

    let resultObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this._log.debug('resultObservable');
      this.tryReActivateToken().then(
        (result) => {
          this._log.debug('resultObservable#then#result: ' + result);
          if (result === true) {
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token);
            headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            // headers.append('Accept', 'json');

            this._log.debug(this.access_token);
            let superGetObs = super.get(url, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

            superGetObs.subscribe(
              (next) => { observer.onNext(next); },
              (error) => { observer.onError(error); },
              () => { observer.onCompleted(); }
            );
          } else {
            observer.onError(new Error('Could not log you in automatically'));
          }
        }, (error) => { this._log.debug('resultObservable#then#error: ' + error); observer.onError(error); });
    });

    return resultObservable;
  }
```

the error I get is: http://pastebin.com/BBcdc9sy

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rxjs Subject next or onNext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555727/rxjs-subject-next-or-onnext)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RxJs 5 [observer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html)'s methods were renamed. You should use `error` instead of `onError`.

Comment: is this the same for onNext and onComplete ?

Comment: Do you have any idea why changing `let superGetObs = super.get(url, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true });` to `let superGetObs = super.get(url, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true }).retry(3);`  produces this error: http://pastebin.com/ScrzsNh0

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote wrong syntax 'onError'. True one is 'error'. You can try this, i hope it solves your problem ;

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this._log.debug('SecureHttpService#get: ' + url);

    let resultObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this._log.debug('resultObservable');
      this.tryReActivateToken().then(
        (result) => {
          this._log.debug('resultObservable#then#result: ' + result);
          if (result === true) {
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token);
            headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            // headers.append('Accept', 'json');

            this._log.debug(this.access_token);
            let superGetObs = super.get(url, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

            superGetObs.subscribe(
              (next) => { observer.onNext(next); },
              (error) => { observer.error(error); },
              () => { observer.onCompleted(); }
            );
          } else {
            observer.onError(new Error('Could not log you in automatically'));
          }
        }, (error) => { this._log.debug('resultObservable#then#error: ' + error); observer.onError(error); });
    });

    return resultObservable;
  }
```